# htaccess auto redirect while attemp to view direct content

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently administrating some art website that contains lots of photos and other content files and it bugs me that ppl find a way around scripting and are accessing stuff directly, they download our copyright protected materials.

I was thinking about htaccess file that do the following:

- someone type in address directly to the browser: http://www.mydomain.com/photos/photo.jpg
- htaccess triggers and instead of showing the content - it redirects right away to: http://www.mydomain.com/ (this is important to do redirect before picture is displayed)
- redirect is extremely important not just some preventing without redirect, but if someone attempts to use sowftware to download content via providing link to it then it rejects request

my knowledge about htaccess is really thin i could use a help on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mydomain.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.jpg|gif$ /nolinking.html [R]
```

If you try enter `http://www.mydomain.com/photos/photo.jpg` it will redirect you to `http://www.mydomain.com/nolinking.html`, but it will allow images to be loaded on pages if they are linked to,

Comment: The idea is perfect if i link images somewhere they should load but entering them directly on the server triggers redirect, the problem is that it doesnt work that way, it does redirect properly but images wont load if im not watching them on original server. Any way of fixing that last part ?;)

Comment: So only allow access if they are embedded on a website?

Comment: yeah with this code you can only watch images if you are on website, if you display them somewhere else its blank with "x" in corner says not avialable

Comment: If you are going to embed the images on specific websites you can add them as a `RewriteCond`, otherwise as far as I know I don't think it's possible.

Comment: but if i add to rewrite they can also access them directly and its exactly what i dont want;d idea was to show but not allow - redirect instead if attempted, there is really now way to accomplish this ? ;(

Comment: Adding the website will only allow it to be embed on that site, users won't be able to directly access the images.